# For Each Loop for a Column

Tags: vba, excel

Hello I'm trying to loop one if-else for all column. But it returns 1004 error constantly

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Sheets("InputRAW").Columns(2).Copy Destination:=Sheets("OutputALL").Columns(1)

    With ActiveSheet
        Lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    Dim rRng As Range
    Set rRng = Range("A1:A" & Lastrow)

    For Each cell In rRng.Cells
        If IsEmpty(cell) Then
            Worksheets("InputRAW").Range("C" & cell).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("OutputALL").Range("B" & cell)
        Else
            Worksheets("InputRAW").Range("A" & cell).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("OutputALL").Range("B" & cell)
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: `Worksheets("InputRAW").Range("C" & cell.ROW).Copy` (same for destination)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use "cell.Row" instead of "cell"

```
For Each cell In rRng.Cells
    If IsEmpty(cell) Then
        Worksheets("InputRAW").Range("C" & cell.Row).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("OutputALL").Range("B" & cell.Row)
    Else
        Worksheets("InputRAW").Range("A" & cell.Row).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("OutputALL").Range("B" & cell.Row)
    End If
Next
```